# svg image animation browser compaitiblity

Tags: animation, svg, cross-browser, webkit

I am animating svg image by modifying there code in the source code.
It runs perfectly fine in torch browser but is not animating in google chrome and other browsers.
I am using this code for animation in the xml file of svg image.

```
<animateColor attributeName="fill" attributeType="XML" from="black" to="grey" dur=".5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>   
<animateColor attributeName="stroke" attributeType="XML" from="black" to="grey" dur=".5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```

Comment: Thank you sir,your answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointedOut the correct way to animate the svg image was to use animate tag since animateColor tag is depreceated.

```
<animate attributeName="fill" attributeType="XML" from="black" to="grey" dur=".5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>   
<animate attributeName="stroke" attributeType="XML" from="black" to="grey" dur=".5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `<animateColor>` as it's deprecated. Some UAs implement it, some don't.

Fortunately `<animate>` can be used anywhere `<animateColor>` can and the syntax is the same so just global search and replace animateColor with animate and you should be all set.